# How add a class to select element <option> tag in Contact Form 7?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm a big fan of Contact Form 7 and I always come to a point where I need to make a few extended customization to my forms. This time, I'm quite frustrated trying to add different classes to a select element `<option>` tag with no avail.

What I'm trying to do is implement a cool style and effect to dropdown lists from [Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/) into [my own CF7 form](http://cl.ly/image/0H3N3h250V2L) - as the screenshot shows it works nicely, however, icons are not showing because so that they can be displayed the `<option>`tag within a select element needs to have its own class.

For e.g:

First, I need to create a select element with id="cd-dropdown" and class="cd-select", until here, this can be easily achieved with the CF7 shortcode generator as bellow.

```
[select* select-profissao id:cd-dropdown class:cd-select "Professional" "Nurse" "Lawyer"]
```

Contact Form 7 aforementioned shortcode generates the html select element to something like this:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
 <option value="" selected>Professional</option>
 <option value="" >Nurse</option>
 <option value="" >Lawyer</option>
</select>
```

But I'd like to be able to add a class to the `<option>` tag. Is it even possible to achieve that by using the CF7 shortcode generator? Are there any workarounds in order to achieve that maybe by using javascript/jQuery or even PHP?

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
 <option value="" selected>Professional</option>
 <option value="" class="icon-nurse">Nurse</option>
 <option value="" class="icon-lawyer">Lawyer</option>
</select>
```

I'd really appreciate any guidance regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in the plugin files to see where it generates the options and edit as you please.

Comment: Hey @Billy Mathews, txt for the hint! Anyway, I'm not sure I'm able to accomplish that, I mean, I believe that would require a deep tweaking within the plugin core files to create extra options to add a unique class to each of the <option> tags, store everything in database and so on. But I'll keep researching it anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just add this jquery:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rvpatel/7wa3V/

```
    $( "#cd-dropdown option" ).addClass(function(index) {
     return "icon-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @ravipatel, It worked great for me! It would be really helpful if the WPCF7 development team could make this feature available within the plugin's options. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to add classes to option client side using jQuery (assuming you are already using jQuery for the SimpleDropDownEffects plugin)

Example Select rendered by contact form:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Choose a weather condition</option>
    <option value="1">Sun</option>
    <option value="2">Clouds</option>
    <option value="3">Snow</option>
    <option value="4">Rain</option>
    <option value="5">Windy</option>
</select>
```

Add following javascript on the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    myClassNames = ["", "icon-sun", "icon-cloudy", "icon-weather", "icon-rainy", "icon-windy"];
    jQuery.each(jQuery("#cd-dropdown option"), function(index, value) {
        jQuery(value).addClass(myClassNames[index]);
    });
    //do SimpleDropDownEffects plugin here after classes are added.
});
```

Pros: No hacking into plugin files, no update plugin woes.
Cons: class names are had-coded in js

Answer (score 0):

Modify in your plugin dir `modules/select.php` wpcf7_select_shortcode_handler function:

```
function wpcf7_select_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

    if ( empty( $tag->name ) )
        return '';

    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error( $tag->name );

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );

    if ( $validation_error )
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';

    $atts = array();

    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_option( 'id', 'id', true );
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );

    if ( $tag->is_required() )
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';

    $atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';

    $defaults = array();

    if ( $matches = $tag->get_first_match_option( '/^default:([0-9_]+)$/' ) )
        $defaults = explode( '_', $matches[1] );

    $multiple = $tag->has_option( 'multiple' );
    $include_blank = $tag->has_option( 'include_blank' );
    $first_as_label = $tag->has_option( 'first_as_label' );

    $name = $tag->name;
    $values = $tag->values;
    $labels = $tag->labels;

    $empty_select = empty( $values );

    if ( $empty_select || $include_blank ) {
        array_unshift( $labels, '---' );
        array_unshift( $values, '' );
    } elseif ( $first_as_label ) {
        $values[0] = '';
    }

    $html = '';

    $posted = wpcf7_is_posted();

    foreach ( $values as $key => $value ) {
        $selected = false;

        // changed here
        if (! ( $attributes = json_decode($value, true) ) ) {
            $attributes = array(
                'value' => $value
            );
        } else {
            $value = (isset($attributes['value'])) ? $attributes['value'] : null;
        }

        if ( $posted && ! empty( $_POST[$name] ) ) {
            if ( $multiple && in_array( esc_sql( $value ), (array) $_POST[$name] ) )
                $selected = true;
            if ( ! $multiple && $_POST[$name] == esc_sql( $value ) )
                $selected = true;
        } else {
            if ( ! $empty_select && in_array( $key + 1, (array) $defaults ) )
                $selected = true;
        }

            // changed here
            $item_atts = array('selected' => $selected ? 'selected' : '' );
            $item_atts = array_merge($attributes, $item_atts);

        $item_atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $item_atts );

        $label = isset( $labels[$key] ) ? $labels[$key] : $value;

        $html .= sprintf( '<option %1$s>%2$s</option>',
            $item_atts, esc_html( $label ) );
    }

    if ( $multiple )
        $atts['multiple'] = 'multiple';

    $atts['name'] = $tag->name . ( $multiple ? '[]' : '' );

    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><select %2$s>%3$s</select>%4$s</span>',
        $tag->name, $atts, $html, $validation_error );

    return $html;
}
```

Now you can call the plugin as before, or send the value of json(all keys rendered as attribute), i.e.:

```
[select* select-profissao id:cd-dropdown class:cd-select '{"value":"Professional","class":"mytestclass"}' '{"value":"Nurse","more-attr":"Nurse Attribute"}']
```

Unfortunately I can not test this (No installed wordpress).

Comment: Hacking the plugin is not a great idea. On updates changes will disappear.