# HIding or Showing Dropdown Options Based On Another Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, contact-form

I have 16 fields that need to be sorted by state. Originally, I made it so that there was four different divs because there's four different states people can choose from.

However, I ran into the issue of emails not going to the right people because the 16 fields are agents that people can choose and those agents need to have an email sent to them if they're chosen.

I keep finding multiple solutions for showing and hiding different divs but how do I hide or show options in a single sub-drop down menu?

Parent Dropdown Menu

- State 1
- State 2
- State 3
- State 4

Agent Dropdown Menu

- Agent 1
- Agent 2
- Agent 3
- Etc (all the way to agent 16)

How can I make it so that when a user selects State 1, it only shows a few options from the agent dropdown menu? The only solutions I can find are ones that have you split the sub-menu into different divs. We're using Contact Form 7 and the only thing people can see are the names but the emails are attached and those agents have to get an email when someone selects them.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger off the change state in a select dropdown and hide options in the second one

HTML

```
<select id="s1">
    <option disabled selected>pick an option</option> 
    <option data-id="1">option 1</option>    
    <option data-id="2">option 2</option>  
</select>

<select id="s2">
    <option class="1">sub option 1</option>   
    <option class="1">sub option 2</option> 
    <option class="1">sub option 3</option> 
    <option class="1">sub option 4</option> 

    <option class="2">sub option 5</option> 
    <option class="2">sub option 6</option> 
    <option class="2">sub option 7</option> 
    <option class="2">sub option 8</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$("#s1").on("change", function(){
    var id = $("#s1 :selected").data("id");
    if(id == 1){
        $(".1").show();
        $(".2").hide();
    }
    if(id == 2){
        $(".1").hide();
        $(".2").show();
    }
});
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5g2qv6e6/) I created

UPDATE:

In response to your comments you can add classes via Jquery like this:

```
var count = 0;
   $("#s2 option").each(function(){
       if(count < 4){
           $(this).addClass("1");
       }
       else $(this).addClass("2");
       count++;
});
```

This just uses a simple counter to add a "1" class to the first half of the options and then switch over to a "2" class for the second half.

Comment: This would be beautiful. Do you by chance know of any way to add a class to options in Contact Form 7? Currently it looks like


`<option value="Option1">Option1</option>`

Comment: Never heard of 'Contact Form 7' but can you not just add classes to the options?

Comment: Actually a quick google brought up this question so have a look... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984291/how-add-a-class-to-select-element-option-tag-in-contact-form-7

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select onchange="changeValues()" id="main-dd">
    <option value="0">State 1</option>
    <option value="1">State 2</option>
    <option value="2">State 3</option>
    <option value="3">State 4</option>
</select>

<select id="agent-dd"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
 var AgentDDValues = [
                        ['Agent 1','Agent 2'],
                        ['Agent 3'],
                        ['Agent 4'],['Agent 5'],
                        ['Agent 6'],['Agent 7'],['Agent 8']
                    ];

  function changeValues(){
      var e = document.getElementById("main-dd");
      var selVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      $("#agent-dd").empty();

      for(var i=0;i<AgentDDValues[selVal].length;i++){
       $("#agent-dd").append('<option>'+AgentDDValues[selVal][i]+'</option>');
    }
```

}